# Can't select database - Wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, wamp

When I download a new wordpress from wordpress.org and then paste it into my www folder of WAMP, then create a new database in phpmyadmin, then go to localhost and click the wordpress site, it asks to create the config file, and enter the database details, and i do that correctly, but when I click submit, it says "Can’t select database".

Any Idea why this is?

I already have a local wordpress site that started  saying error connecting to database. The config settings are all correct so i tried to download a fresh wordpress site and use it and I cannot even set up a fresh one. I have never encountered a fresh wordpress site not working like this before.

I did a msqldump of my old site so that my boss could put it on his server. Not sure if that is relevant.

Cheers.

Comment: check your config details are correct

Comment: Is the wordpress database still available? Can you look at it's content without using wordpress (like using phpmyadmin)?

Comment: check your DB and DB user role permissions

Answer (score 14):

Please don't overcomplicate.

In the "Database Host" field add "localhost: e.g. in my case "localhost:3308" solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who's still looking for solutions to this problem - please, check again your wp-config.php database credentials again. I had the same problem today and tried to over-complicate the matter by searching for advanced solutions, while I had a space in my DB_NAME field (was supposed to be 'wpdb' and was ' wpdb').

This space completely messed up my connection, I was even close to reinstalling the whole thing and losing all data.

Answer (score 2):

If using LAMP -

Make sure that all privileges are granted for that database to the created mysql user. Under your MYSQL shell use the below

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO database_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';
```

Where,

database_name = your database name as per wp-config.php

database_user = your user name as per wp-config.php

userpassword = your user password as per wp-config.php

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password'' at line 1`

Comment: That one liner is described as deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111847/identified-by-password-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

By default

**username** : **root**

**password** : leave it blank

**database host** : **localhost**

**table_prefix** : **wp_**

Answer (score 1):

please create your database with name 'wordpress' before installing wordpress

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either you have not created a database or your wp-config file is not set up correctly. Have you edited wp-config.php file of wordpress and provided correct database name and user credentials. See [Famous 5 minute installation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install) of wordpress for details.

Comment: Yes thanks. On the last step of that installation (going to the url) it says "Error establishing a database connection". Is it connected to me cancelling my subscription?

Comment: Can you show your wp-config.php file code. (removing password)

Comment: First make sure database name is `the_commons`. Secondly root by default has empty password so make sure in wp-config.php your password is set like: `define('DB_PASSWORD', '');`

Comment: Just discovered that none of my databases work on any of my web sites any more. I have WAMP all services running including mysql

Comment: Before messing with databases create new user with all privileges and use it.

Comment: Have you recently installed something that comes with its own MySQL. In other words are you running two MySQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

It took me way too long to discover that my msql databases were not working on any other websites either. I reinstalled Wamp Server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the wp-config.php file.
I had the same error and the problem was related with the quotes:
‘root’ vs 'root'

edit: *the correct one is single quote*

```
'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, **the solution was giving** `wp_user` **all permissions on the** `wp_db` **database.**

I achieved this using the command line interpreter (CLI):

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL ON `wp_db`.* TO `wp_user`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
MariaDB [(none)]> exit;
```

After these operations, I restarted the database:

```
$ systemctl restart mysql
```

Of course, the *database name* (*wp_db*), *username* (*wp_user*), and *password of the user* (*pass*) can be different.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that when I granted permissions to the DB user the host did not match what was in the wp_config.php

```
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
```

I was granting rights with

```
GRANT ALL ON databaseName.* TO 'UserName'@'127.0.0.1';
```

This gave me access when I was connected to the local host through ssh but It did not match wp_config.php. so I had to Grant like this then it all worked.

```
GRANT ALL ON databaseName.* TO 'UserName'@'localhost';
```

Comment: For MariaDB yes it's 3306 and 3308 for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

For Mariadb hostname should be localhost:3306 and for MySQL localhost:3308.this fixed my error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to transfer databases between WAMP server installations.

I tried opening PhpMyAdmin on new PC, then got the port of MySql server (:3308) and added this port into `DB_HOST ('localhost:3308')`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create the database yourself.
Visit http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin5
create a new database with the name you prefer.
Don't add any table names, just use the name you choose for the database in the WordPress setup

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this problem. The form fields auto-populate with placeholders. You have to type over the placeholder information to enter the data. Took me over an hour to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

After doing an **Acronis profile restore** I encountered this same issue and I spent a long time trying to figure out what the issue could be I found that even though my user was appearing in the list of users it did not have any privileges set up.

I was able to check the privileges by going into phpMyAdmin and checking privileges on the db.

I was using **cPanel** and so I did the following:

- Under the databases header I selected 'MySQL Databases'
- Then scroll down to the heading 'Add User To Database'
- Select the user that is in your wp-config file
- Click 'Add User'
- Give them the SELECT Privilege
- Click 'Add/Edit User'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34863958)