# issue with connecting mysql with ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to connect database at the moment I got this an error:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `simple_development`.* TO 'rails_user'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>    syntax to use near IDENTIFIED BY "Password" at line 1

Comment: Hello, you need to post a more detailed question if you expect asnwers, for example, the code that is giving you the error.

Comment: Doesn't even worth asking "what is your question?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this: ["IDENTIFIED BY 'password'" in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111847/identified-by-password-in-mysql)

"

In summary, use `CREATE` to create a user, and use `GRANT` to add privileges:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

"

Comment: Yes its works but now when i try to :

Comment: Ok Thanks its works but now when I try to type the following command: rails db:schema;dump
that time getting this error:

 rails aborted! Mysql2:Error: Authentication plugins ' caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: the specified module could not be found bin/rails:4:in '<main>'