# WordPress with local MySQL server: Cannot select created database as root

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost, admin, mamp

Even though I am root and I can log into my local mysql server as root, the WordPress Setup Configuration prevents me from selecting a database I created:

[image]

But I select one of the ones that I did not create like `sys`, then it seems to connect just fine. What is happening? What am I doing wrong?

edit:
Here is what I am inputting into the WP (censoring my password), and this setup configuration generates a `wp-config.php` file. Again this only seems to work for databases like `sys`.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the solution. I follow these instructions (without sudo) in order to completely purge my mysql installation: https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d. By reinstalling my mysql, everything was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the database schema `api`. You can create it by simply running this query:

```
CREATE DATABASE api CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

When the schema is created, make sure the user (which you provided on the wordpress page) have all rights on the table. Like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON api.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

If you still are experiencing issues, take a look at this post: [Can't select database - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801992/cant-select-database-wordpress)

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password'' at line 1`

Comment: You will have to change `'your_password'` to your actual SQL-password.

Comment: Yes, of course I changed my `your_password` to what I actually put, but I am not going to post that online.